# Building a table that summarizes data about another table - Optimization suggestions?

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-optimization

I am trying to build a table that summarizes how many times pages in our Wiki references certain macros.

I have built a temporary table called @currentpages that with 55k rows that looks like this:

```
DECLARE @currentpages table(
ContentID       NUMERIC(19,0) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
PageTitle       VARCHAR(255) NULL,
SpaceKey            VARCHAR(255) NULL,
OriginalAuthor  VARCHAR(255) NULL,
LastChangedBy   VARCHAR(255) NULL,
LastChangedDt   VARCHAR(10) NULL,
ContentBody         TEXT NULL);
```

and another table that looks like this:

```
DECLARE @usage table(
SpaceKey        VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
Macro1      NUMERIC(19,0) NULL,
Macro2      NUMERIC(19,0) NULL,
Macro3              NUMERIC(19,0) NULL);
```

(I've simplified the above; it actually has about 40 columns like Macro1, Macro2, etc.)  I'm trying to get counts of how many references there are (in @currentpages) to these various macros.

I initialize the @usage table by creating a row for each possible SpaceKey value, zeroing out all of the Macro"x" counters:

```
INSERT INTO @usage (SpaceKey, Macro1, Macro2, Macro3)
SELECT S.spacekey, 0, 0, 0
FROM spaces     S
ORDER BY S.spacekey
```

Then I run the first of several UPDATE statements to identify each macro reference:

```
UPDATE @usage
SET U.AdvancedSearch = C.Counter
FROM @usage                 U
INNER JOIN (SELECT SpaceKey, COUNT(*) AS Counter 
    FROM @currentpages 
    WHERE ContentBody LIKE '%{search-%' GROUP BY SpaceKey) C 
        ON U.SpaceKey = C.SpaceKey
```

This appears to work fine, but it runs a very long time.  Is there a more efficient way to do what I'm trying to do?

This database is on SQL Server 2005.

Many thanks,
Betsy

Comment: I'm a bit confused, you are setting AdvancedSearch in the last query, but I did not see that column declared in @usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't make a column per macro, but make a table like this.

```
DECLARE @macrotype table(
    type      int          NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
  , MacroName varchar(100) NOT NULL 
  , mask      varchar(100) NOT NULL 
)

DECLARE @usage table(
  SpaceKey    VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
, MacroType   int NOT NULL 
, MacroCount  int NOT NULL 
)
```

Once you have that you can populate it by running

```
  INSERT INTO @macrotype VALUES (1, 'search', '%{search-%')
                              , (2, 'yadayada', '%{yadayada-%')
                              , ...

  DECLARE @c int, @m varchar(100)
  DECLARE c CURSOR READ_ONLY FOR SELECT type, mask FROM @macrotype
  OPEN c

  FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @t, @m

  WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO @usage (SpaceKey, MacroType, MacroCount)
      SELECT SpaceKey
           , @t
           , COUNT(*) AS Counter 
        FROM @currentpages
       WHERE ContentBody LIKE @m
    GROUP BY SpaceKey
    FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @t, @m
  END
  CLOSE c
  DEALLOCATE c
```

At the end of your story you can query the @usage table to make counts in whatever form you wish.

```
  SELECT MacroName, count = count(*)
    FROM @usage u
    JOIN @macrotype m
      ON u.MacroType - m.type
GROUP BY MacroName
```

On 55k records this will run for a few minutes.

Comment: Thank you for this example. It still runs for 30 minutes, but I think it's more efficient than what I had before... and it's cleaner too. :-D

Answer (score 1):

1. Investigate full text search. ([Full Text Search @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms142571%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx))
   I don't have any experience with it, so can not offer advice.
2. Instead of querying @CurrentPages once per macro, get all the macro counts at once.  Something like:

   ```
   INSERT INTO @usage (SpaceKey, Macro1, Macro2, Macro3)
   SELECT S.spacekey
       , count(case when ContentBody LIKE '%Search Macro 1%' 
           then 1 else null end) as Macro1_Count
       , count(case when ContentBody LIKE '%Search Macro 2%' 
           then 1 else null end) as Macro2_Count
       , count(case when ContentBody LIKE '%Search Macro 3%' 
           then 1 else null end) as Macro=3Count
   FROM spaces S
   LEFT OUTER JOIN @CurrentPages C ON C.SpaceKey = S.SpaceKey
   GROUP BY S.spacekey
   ```

Comment: Full text search is not an option because the search terms contain a dash (-). Wrapping all the searches in one query is a nice approach though.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine any performance hits are going to come from the subquery containing the LIKE clause since it's going to be doing a full table scan. I don't really see what else would slow this down too much.

You could test that by running just the sub-query and comparing the time it takes to return to the time the entire update takes for one of your columns.

Comment: Would any other approach be more efficient?  I need to run this in Production, but if I'm doing (roughly) 100 LIKE's, it's gonna run 4evah!

Comment: In SQL? Not really - if you need to search for text within a varchar field, thats just what you're going to have to do. The other option would be to write a script/utility in another language (.net, etc.) that can more easily handle string manipulation/searching.